# Python dict call function as value

Tags: python, json, function, loops

I'm creating a dict in python using returned json.

one of the values I want to be a shortuuid, so I put a function as the value.
I want that function called and the value replaced with what that function returns.

Is this correct ?

```
        tvMSG = {'fromEMAIL': uEmail, 'toCHANNELID': channelID, 'timeSENT': uTime}
             for msgkey, subdict, instakey in (('profilePIC', 'user', 'profile_picture'),
                         ('userNAME', 'user', 'username'),
                         ('msgBODY', 'caption', 'text'),
                         ('mainCONTENT','images', 'standard_resolution',)
                         ('tvshowID', shortuuid.uuid())):



   this is the key/value in question:
            ('tvshowID', shortuuid.uuid())):
```

This is the error I get:

```
        TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

If not how do I make it work?

Comment: Is it not working as is?

Comment: no, I get this error.... TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: It is the correct way of doing it. However you are iterating through a list a 3-tuple, and the last one is only a 2-tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from a missing comma. The line:

```
('mainCONTENT','images', 'standard_resolution',)
```

should actually be:

```
('mainCONTENT','images', 'standard_resolution'),
```

That's why you were getting the error `'tuple' object is not callable`, you were calling `('any','tuple')('arguments')`.

Comment: nice catch! fixed 2 problems...the error and str8ened the code out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints @ThierryJ.

```
  tvMSG = {'fromEMAIL': uEmail, 'toCHANNELID': channelID, 'timeSENT': uTime, 'tvshowID: shortuuid.uuid()}
         for msgkey, subdict, instakey in (('profilePIC', 'user', 'profile_picture'),
                     ('userNAME', 'user', 'username'),
                     ('msgBODY', 'caption', 'text'),
                     ('mainCONTENT','images', 'standard_resolution')):
```

There was no need to do any iteration.
I just took that call out of the loop and put it in the variable above the loop.